Bounds of Pearson correlation coefficients for $(X,Z)$ knowing those for $(X,Y)$ and $(Y,Z)$
Assume $X,Y,Z$ are three variables over a set of data (say, a finite set of data to avoid discussions of convergence).  Suppose we know the Pearson correlation coefficient $r_{X,Y}$ and $r_{Y,Z}$: given these data, what bounds (ideally sharp) can we put on $r_{X,Z}$?
If I am not mistaken, the question is equivalent to the following: for a positive semidefinite matrix with a diagonal of $1$, if we know the coefficients $(i,j)$ and $(j,k)$ in the matrix, what (ideally sharp) bounds can we put on the coefficient $(i,k)$?
Surely this is a classical problem and has been considered before, but I don't know what terms to search for.

The key lemmas to look up are equivalent conditions for a matrix to be positive semi definite. The relevant one is the characterisation in terms of principal minors.

@RagibZaman Ah yes! Sylvester's criterion gives the condition $r_{XY}^2 + r_{YZ}^2 + r_{XZ}^2 - 2 r_{XY} , r_{YZ} , r_{XZ} - 1 \leq 0$ (this being the determinant of the relevant $3\times 3$ minor). Which in turn means $r_{XZ}$ must be between $r_{XY} , r_{YZ} \pm \sqrt{(1-r_{XY}^2)(1-r_{YZ}^2)}$.

As was pointed to me somewhere else, the Pearson correlation coefficient can also be viewed as the cosine of the angle of the value vectors normalized and rescaled (i.e., a spherical distance). So the inequality is then obtained by taking the triangle inequality on the angles and adding adding cosines. Which (taking into account the formula for $\cos(u\pm v)$) yields the same inequality as in the previous comment.

The question has been mostly answered in the comments, the bound being
$$
r_{XY}^2 + r_{YZ}^2 + r_{XZ}^2 - 2 r_{XY} \, r_{YZ} \, r_{XZ} \leq 1
$$
by Sylvester's criterion.  However, there are a few additional comments one can make on the convex 3D shape (elliptical tetrahedron or “elliptotope”) defined by this inequality: its boundary contains the vertices and edges of a regular tetrahedron, yet all its cross-sections perpendicular to one of the axes are ellipses.  For more about this, see P. J. Rousseeuw & G. Molenberghs, “The Shape of Correlation Matrices”, The American Statistician, 48 (1994) 276–279.
This web page by Ben Bolker further explores this shape and how to plot it.
